# Organize values in an array but keep items "paired together"

Tags: c#, arrays

So for my homework assignment I need to write a type of program that has the user type in the persons name and then their score. It then needs to find the highest, lowest, and the average score and list the player that achieved each one.

```
static void Main()
{
    string userInput;

    Console.Write("Please enter bowler's first name and then a score then use a comma to seperate plays\nExample: Elliott 200,John 180,Jane 193\nPlease enter values here: ");
    userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    char[] delimiters = new char[] { ' ', ','};
    string[] parts = userInput.Split(delimiters);

    for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
    {
    Console.WriteLine(parts[i]);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();

}//End Main()
```

As you can see I've figured out how to split the input, but I don't know how to organize them and pair them together. I've been looking online for an answer and have heard of lists but I've never used them. It this even possible on an array? Do I need to do this on two different arrays?

I have also tried splitting into two arrays but it has a convert issue

```
    string userInput;
    const int ZERO = 0;
    const int ONE = 1;
    const int TEN = 10;
    string[] parsedInput = new string[TEN];
    string[] name = new string[TEN];
    int[] score = new int[TEN];


    for (int i = 0; i < TEN; ++i)
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter bowler's first name and then a score\nExample: Name 200\nPlease enter values here: ", i);
        userInput = Console.ReadLine();
        parsedInput = userInput.Split();
        name = parsedInput[ZERO];
        score = int.Parse(parsedInput[ONE]);
    }
```

Comment: Create a list of classes. Or take a few hours to learn more about programming, data structures and so on.

Answer (score 1):

When you say you don't know how to pair them together, this is what a class is for.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Score { get; set; }
}
```

Once you have that, you're on the right track with using a List instead of an array (not that you couldn't use arrays but this would be the preferred way)

```
List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
```

You can then use a loop to go through your list and access the properties.

```
foreach(Person person in people)
{
    Console.WriteLine(person.Name + ", " + person.Score.ToString());
}
```

The other answer posted is fine, but you should probably focus on something like this first if you are just learning.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful reply, but I need to put the name and score by each other on the same line. Would I need to create two different classes (a string for the name and an int for the score) for this? I tried user a split but I get convert issues for name and score. I put in new code on top

Comment: No the point of the class is that a person object can have both a name and a score. See my edit above inside of the loop for an example of printing the name and score on the same line.

Comment: My teacher hasn't talked about classes yet, so I had a question. when you have the Console.WriteLine(person.Name does the .Name assign a new row or column which then fills in the value starting on block 0? So kind of like two arrays side by side?

Comment: Not really but it more or less has the same result as what you're describing. Do a quick study on classes/creating objects, Lists, and Lists of objects. Having said that if your teacher hasn't gone over it you may just want to use two arrays for now. Just have the indexes match up (name with score) and use a for loop.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read more on the terms you mentioned. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can do that using simple array of string. But I'm not going to give you code like that. You should definitely spend much more time to learn about classes, arrays, lists, loops, etc. **You're not gonna learn anything unless you do it by yourself.**

And just to show you, how it could be done when you know the language you're using well: LINQ one-liner to get a list of anonymous type objects, sorted descending by the value:

```
var items = input.Split(',')
                 .Select(x => x.Split(' '))
                 .Select(x => new { name = x[0], value = int.Parse(x[1]) })
                 .OrderByDescending(x => x.value)
                 .ToList();
```

And taking what you need from the list:

```
// min/max are items, so both .name and .value are there
var maxItem = items.First();
var minItem = items.Last();

// average is just a number
var average = items.Average(x => (double)x.value);
```

Comment: Haha, I'd pay to see the face of his teacher when he'll see this.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault I've updated my answer with a little text. It explains why I did it that way.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek - this solution is great, but the teacher is never going to believe the student came up with this on their own. :-)

Comment: I mean, he's obviously at a very _very_ basic C# programming level (there's even a comment to point out the end of Main), I doubt the teacher will believe he even know what an anonymous type is.

Comment: May I say that this chaining of operations takes the cake as a key example of why functional languages are indecipherable.  I would suggest some clearly named intermediate results that can be tested, passed in/out.

Comment: @AndyzSmith: Boo! Hiss! Don't confuse not being pablum with being unreadable. For those who have made the effort of actually **learning** the tools and languages, functional programming languages become **much easier to read**, given sensible formatting as Marcin uses here.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens don't like it.  I want to know , by way of a clear variable name, what each operation is supposed to accomplish.  That way I can use a piece for something else or more easily detect bugs, based on the intent.